# How to access a dynamically generated id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say the ids are generated dynamically, How can i access those ids.?
I want when i click a field an id of the clicked field to be displayed.

```html
 <input class="challengee" id="challengee0" placeholder="challengee0"><br>
  <input class="challengee" id="challengee1" placeholder="challengee1"><br>
  <input class="challengee" id="challengee2" placeholder="challengee2"><br>
```

Comment: Btw the you should add a bit of code to your question. Like how did you try to get the ids. It would give us a clear insight of you want to do.

Comment: Be careful, your HTML is un-readable and full of mistakes (mainly unclosed tags, and `<center>` [is not supported anymore](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you get all nodes with the `.challengee` class? And then accessing them with the id. For example:

```
var $challengees = Array.from($('ul > .challengee'))
var ids = $challengees.map(challengee => $(challengee).attr('id'))
```

Would give your an array containing all of the IDs.

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ejxLxdn/)

**Edit:** if what you want is to get that id on an event, it doesn't matter how it generated. You could do:

```
$challengees.on('focus', function() {
    console.log(this.id)
})
```

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j22jwf7w/)

Comment: lets say these ids are dynamically generated and i want when i click in one of this input field, jquery must display the id of the input field i clicked.                                                                                            <input class="challengee" id="challengee0">
  <input class="challengee" id="challengee2">
  <input class="challengee" id="challengee3">

Comment: Maybe you should specify it in the question, because it's currently not what you asked. I edited my answer btw.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what im asking for.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to validate the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet, it give you the list of ids.

```
var ids = $('input.challengee[id^=challengee]').map(function(){
   return this.id;
}).get();
```